# Use the EMMA test the android unit test coverage, make some errors

Tags: android, unit-testing, emma

When i user the EMMA test the android unit test coverage by device, make some errors:

。。。。
 [exec] failed to copy '/data/data/com.gnet.meetme/coverage.ec' to 'coverage
.ec': Permission denied
。。。。。

Note:My device has been rooted.
I found, use "**mount -o rw,remount -t yaffs2 /dev/block/mtdblock3 /system**" command can change system permission, who can you tell me which command can change the data/data permission same as system?

thanks a lot.

Comment: I am getting this error as well for the command: ant clean emma debug install test.
Have you found a solution yet?